# Error when building with XCODE

Tags: xcode, frameworks, 8thwall-xr

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARImageAnchor", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in libXRPlugin.a(ios-arkit-sensor.o)
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARReferenceImage", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in libXRPlugin.a(ios-arkit-sensor.o)
```

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Hello! That's the error I get when trying to compile Demo app from 8thwall

I suppose that's related to a frame work error, any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What version of XCode are you using? As per the 8th Wall XR documentation, a version of `XCode 9.3 or higher` is required.

https://docs.8thwall.com/#requirements